# Find and open a file by fzf in a new tab

Tags: vimrc, fzf

I've configured my VIM to find and open a file by fzf:

```
nmap <c-x><c-f> :Files<cr>
```

It works fine, but I wanna open the file in a new tab instead of the current tab with the same shortcut keys.

Comment: @filbranden When I press Ctrl-t it says about tags and Ctrl-T in my Gnome Terminal will open a new tab in Terminal generally. Do you know what's the function behind it that I set a shortcut key for it?

Comment: @filbranden Thanks a lot! It worked!

Comment: @filbranden you'll post as an answer? or I do it?

Comment: I'll do it. Thanks for confirming this works for you!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: `<c-x><c-f>` is for filename completion - useful to insert a path in buffer. Not a good idea to remap that. I have `<leader>f` to open `:Files<CR>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Vim fzf plug-in has a native feature to open the selected item in a new tab.

If you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> inside the fzf selection window, it will tell Vim to open the item in a new tab (when applicable.)

See [here](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim#commands), below the table it says:

> Most commands support `CTRL-T` / `CTRL-X` / `CTRL-V` key bindings to open in a new tab, a new split, or in a new vertical split.

If this is acceptable for you, you don't need a new mapping to open files in a new tab, just to use the appropriate Ctrl+key sequence when selecting an entry, to have that entry opened in a new tab (or a split too, since that's also supported.)

Answer (score 0):

Per the [maintainer](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/discussions/2519#discussioncomment-873077) you can also configure `fzf.vim` to open the selected file in a new tab by default by adding this to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
let g:fzf_action = { 'enter': 'tab split' }
```

The accepted solution works as well, I'm just too lazy to include those extra two key strokes.